# Title Wont Center

Tags: html, css

The story title is not centering, when I change it to `h1`, it just disappears. I am really not sure why this is.

```css
storytitle {
  background-color: black;
  font-color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}

ree {
  background-color: black;
  color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<title>Story2</title>

<storytitle style="color:red;text-align:center">
  THiS IS A TEST TITLE </br>
</storytitle>
<ree>
  this is a test body
</ree>
```

Comment: Try using valid HTML.

Comment: put "div" instead of "storytitle" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are not writing HTML.

Error recovery in browsers will create a `storytitle` element with some default styling that includes `display: inline`.

The `text-align` property does not apply to inline elements.

The solution is to write valid HTML. If you use an `h1` element (all else being equal) it will not disappear and, being `display: block` by default, the `text-align` property will apply.

```css
h1{
    background-color:black;
    font-color:#ff0000 ;
    font-size:150%;
    text-align:center;
}
p{
    background-color:black;
    color:#0000ff;
    font-size:100%;
    text-align:right;

}
body{
    background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:red;text-align:center">THiS IS A TEST TITLE</h1>
<p>this is a test paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes:

1. The HTML tags weren't valid HTML tags

   I changed the tags to `h1`, `h2` and `p` (headers and paragraph).
   I assumed you wanted to use *story*, *storytitle* and *ree* as classes, so I did that for you in the code below.

---

2. The styling was redundant

   on your "storytitle" you had the styles `color: red` and `text-align: center`, but they were already applied in your `<style></style>`

---

3. `</br>` is an end tag but doesn't exist, it's `<br>` and `<br />` in HTML5.

---

4. The black `background-color` on your `body` was enough to give our page a black background. Applying the same color background to your elements is in this case unnecessary.

---

Here is the updated version with correct HTML and styling:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.title {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.storytitle {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}

.ree {
  color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Story2</h1>

<h2 class="storytitle">
  THIS IS A TEST TITLE
</h2>

<br />

<p class="ree">
  this is a test body
</p>
```